# why is react-rails not attaching onClick event action to a button?

Tags: reactjs, react-rails

I'm using react-rails gem to add react components into my rails app.
This is a code sample:

> ```
> let b = <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick} id="678">Click me</button>;
> const element = React.createElement(
>   'button',
>   {
>     type: 'button',
>     onClick: this.onClick
>   },
>   'Hello, world!'
> );
> ```

the onClick event action is not being attached to the button, this is the button object props when I log it :

> props : children : "Click me" id : "678" type : "button"

Comment: Where are you defining `onClick()`? `this` might be referring to the the wrong thing.

Comment: the same code works in a react project,I don't know what react-rails does.